# Question about the application of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Assume that $f:[c,d] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and that the functions $a,b,g$ are continuous on $[c,d]$ and differentiable on $(c,d)$.

> Find $F'(x)$ when $F(x)=(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) dt)^2$.

What I did was to let $G(x)=(F(x))^{1/2}= \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) dt$, then by the Fundamental Theorem of calculus and the chain rule, $G'(x)=-f(a(x))a'(x)+f(b(x))b'(x)$.

And then $F(x)=(G(x))^2$, so using the chain rule again, $F'(x)=2G(x)G'(x)$, so combining these together, $F'(x)= 2((F(x))^{1/2})(-f(a(x))a'(x)+f(b(x))b'(x))$.

Is my workings correct for this part?

> The question then asks to find $F'(x)$ when $F(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} g(x)f(t) dt$.

I am not sure about this part, since it contains integrating $g(x)$ with respect to $t$, can I just see $g(x)$ as a constant or is there something I can apply in order to get $F'(x)$?

Comment: At least the choice of symbols is very ambiguous: what's the meaning for a function $a$ being continuous on $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work you've done in the first part is correct. As for the second one, that's just: $F(x) = g(x)\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)dt$, because like you said, g(x) is a constant through the integration process. Now simply use the product rule for differentiating.

Comment: So would the answer be $F'(x)=g'(x)\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)dt + g(x)(-f(a(x))a'(x)+f(b(x))b'(x))$?

Comment: Yes, that would be the answer.